# object centers on cursor while dragging (EventsControls + three.js)

Tags: three.js

I made an ineractive map, using mapbox and three.js.
And when i drag a map I also drag and drop objects on three.js scene, which is a layer over mapbox. Here is a working version: http://test3.stdmed.ru
I have a problem: When i start to drag, objects on a three.js scene automatically center on cursor position, which is not correct, because this effect ruins geopositioning.

A simple effect u can see on this example: http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#controls_events_example
When u click on a checker it centers to your cursor position. But i need to get it dragged without this effect.

Here is my code, used on map:

```
EventsControls2 = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
EventsControls2.attach( plane );

EventsControls2.attachEvent( 'mouseOver', function () {

  controls.enabled = false;
  controls.target0.copy( controls.target );

});

EventsControls2.attachEvent( 'mouseOut', function () {

  controls.reset();
  controls.target.copy( controls.target0 );
  controls.object.position.copy( controls.position0 );
  controls.update();
  controls.enabled = true;

});

EventsControls = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
EventsControls.map = plane;

EventsControls.attachEvent( 'mouseOver', function () {

  this.container.style.cursor = 'pointer';

});

EventsControls.attachEvent( 'mouseOut', function () {

  this.container.style.cursor = 'auto';

});

EventsControls.attachEvent( 'dragAndDrop', function () {

  this.container.style.cursor = 'move';
  //this.focused.position.y = this.previous.y;
  //this.focused.position.x = this.previous.x;


});

EventsControls.attachEvent( 'onclick', function () {

    controls.enabled = false;

});         

EventsControls.attachEvent( 'mouseUp', function () {

  this.container.style.cursor = 'auto';

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EventsControls = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
EventsControls.map = plane;
EventsControls.offsetUse = true;
```

EventsControls.offsetUse = true; <<<<<<<<< This is what u have to add !!!